# Custom FORM authentication in Jakarta EE 8: can't leave login page after authentication

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly

- Java 11
- Jakarta EE 8
- Wildfly 20

I decided to give a try to the new authentication mechanism called "Custom FORM" authentication from Java EE Security that I saw in BalusC's book *The Definitive Guide To JSF in Java EE 8*.

I created a simple application to test it and it's not working. The problem is that after a successful authentication, I'm not redirected to the welcome page, I keep in the login page. It's as if the application didn't recognize that I'm authenticated.

These are the relevant parts of the relevant files:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <display-name>autenticacao-visao</display-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>restricted</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>allowed</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/templates/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>
  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>start.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**UserAuthenticator.java** (performs a simple authentication)

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;
import javax.security.enterprise.CallerPrincipal;
import javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition;
import javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.LoginToContinue;
import javax.security.enterprise.credential.Credential;
import javax.security.enterprise.credential.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.CredentialValidationResult;
import javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStore;

@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
    loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(
        loginPage = "/login.xhtml",
        errorPage = ""
    )
)
@FacesConfig
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserAuthenticator implements IdentityStore
{
    @Override
    public CredentialValidationResult validate(Credential credencial)
    {
        String name = ((UsernamePasswordCredential) credencial).getCaller();
        return new CredentialValidationResult(new CallerPrincipal(name), Set.of("USER"));
    }
}
```

**PagLogin** (the CDI bean)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.security.enterprise.AuthenticationStatus;
import javax.security.enterprise.SecurityContext;
import javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.AuthenticationParameters;
import javax.security.enterprise.credential.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class PagLogin
{
    private String _userName;
    private String _password;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext _facesContext;
    
    @Inject
    private ExternalContext _externalContext;

    @Inject
    private SecurityContext _securityContext;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "User name is required.")
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return _userName;
    }
    
    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        _userName = userName;
    }
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required.")
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return _password;
    }
    
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        _password = password;
    }
    
    public String authenticateUser() throws IOException
    {
        AuthenticationStatus result = executeUserAuthentication();
        if (result == AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS)
        {
            // It really passes here, but I'm not redirected to the start
            // page. I keep in the login page.
            return "/start?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        else if (result == AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE)
        {
            _facesContext.responseComplete();
        }
        else if (result == AuthenticationStatus.SEND_FAILURE)
        {
            _facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid user name and/or password.", null));
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private AuthenticationStatus executeUserAuthentication()
    {
        return _securityContext.authenticate(
            (HttpServletRequest) _externalContext.getRequest(),
            (HttpServletResponse) _externalContext.getResponse(),
            AuthenticationParameters.withParams().credential(
                new UsernamePasswordCredential(_userName, _password))
        );
    }   
}
```

**login.xhtml** (the JSF login page)

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:au="http://desenvolvimento.br/autenticacao">
    
    <ui:define name="titulo">
        Login
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <au:erros />
        <div id="campos">
            <h:outputLabel value="User name:" for="userName" />
            <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{pagLogin.userName}" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="password" />
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{pagLogin.password}" />

            <h:commandButton value="Enter" action="#{pagLogin.authenticateUser}" />
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

But when I click on the *Enter* button I saw that I really get an *AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS*, but I'm not redirected to the *start.xhtml* page, even if I try to change it in the browser address bar manually. It keeps me redirecting to the login page.

After `AuthenticationStatus result = executeUserAuthentication();` if I put this code:

```
boolean authenticated = ((HttpServletRequest) _externalContext.getRequest()).getUserPrincipal() != null;
```

The variable `authenticated` is `true`.

Maybe there's just a little thing missing, but I don't know what it is.

**UPDATE 1**

I noticed that I also get this warn in the application server log after login:

```
16:57:47,217 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Servlet] (default task-2) WELD-000717: Unable to deactivate context org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.LazyHttpConversationContextImpl@56a54798 when destroying request HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /autenticacao/login.xhtml ]
```

I don't know if this has something to do with the problem.

Missing old times when everything was complicated with `<login-config>` in *web.xml* and ugly with `j_security_check`, but **WORKED**.

**UPDATE 2**

I found a workaround. Look at the comments.

**UPDATE 3**

Sylvain Autran created a minimal working example here:

[Login not forwarding correctly with CustomFormAuth and o:form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523627/login-not-forwarding-correctly-with-customformauth-and-oform)

He is using the Payara 5, versions 201 and 2020.2 to execute his example. So, I decided to clone and execute its example that uses `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` in Wildfly 20. When i click the *Submit* button in the login page I get this error, a `NullPointerException` in the JSF implementation:

```
16:20:40,350 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-1) #{login.submit}: java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException: #{login.submit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:71)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1396)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:82)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at deployment.jakartasecurity.war//org.example.view.Login.submit(Login.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:237)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:65)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:66)
    ... 59 more

16:20:40,355 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /jakartasecurity/login.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:71)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1396)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at deployment.jakartasecurity.war//org.example.view.Login.submit(Login.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:237)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.4.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:65)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP10//com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:66)
    ... 59 more
```

So, it seems a problem in Wildfly 20, not the application.

Comment: I changed from `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` to `@FormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` and the application **worked**, the _start.xhtml_ page was finally displayed. Of course, I also had to change the _login.xhtml_ page to use `j_security_check`. Even thought the application is working now, I'm not on control of the authentication mechanism anymore. But that's ok to me.

Comment: Your question does not contain a [mcve]. Can you create one? There might be (hidden) things in your code that prevent it from working. And two others found a clean correct solution. Both AFTER they created a [mcve]. So just complaining like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523627/jakarta-ee-security-login-not-working-with-customformauth does not really help. I'm willing to try to help, but do need a [mcve] for it.

Comment: @Kukeltje I used the same example of _Sylvain Autran_ to test and I'm getting an error in Wildfly 20. I'm not using Payara. There 's a comment here in Sylvain's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523627/jakarta-ee-security-login-not-working-with-customformauth

Comment: Comments and code on your problem should be in your question!

Comment: I cloned and executed Sylvain example in _Wildfly 20_. When the method `Login#continueAuthentication` is executed, I'm redirected to the _500.xhtml_ page with a `NullPointerException` error in the server _JSF_ implementation: `UT005023: Exception handling request to /jakartasecurity/login.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException` at `javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)` So it seems the bug is in _Wildfly_, not in my application or Sylvain's example.

Comment: javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP03? I thought wildfly 20 has jsf 2.3 and please post a full stackteace and the corresponding code (code above is not related) If you want help, put some time in the quality of the question... cheers

Comment: @Kukeltje Well, that's what is in the stacktrace.

Comment: @Kukeltje Question updated to show the full stacktrace.

Comment: Still no [mcve], stacktrace not related to the posted code and no reaction to my JSF api 3.0.0 vs 2.3 'question'. Cheers

Comment: And for me the stacktrace says the NPE is in your code... `org.example.view.Login.submit(Login.java:51)`

Comment: Yes, there's a minimal reproducible example: Sylvain Autran's example (I didn't make any change to it). It shows that  `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` works in Payara 5 and doesn't work in Wildfly 20. Therefore, the problem is in Wildfly.

Comment: [mcve] should be innline, not in a remote link in the answer of a different question. and good luck!

Comment: `org.example.view.Login.submit(Login.java:51)` is this call: `switch (continueAuthentication()) {`. The method `continueAuthentication()` references 5 instance variables: `securityContext` (not null), `externalContext` (not null), `url` (null, but there's no problem), `username` (not null) and `password` (not null). I checked all the variables to see if they were `null`. So, the problem is not in Sylvain's code, the problem is that the method call this method `javax.security.enterprise.SecurityContext.authenticate`. The NPE error happens inside this method.

Comment: Sylvain has `glassfish-web.xml`, do you meed a similar one for WF? And debugged the 'authenticate' method?

Comment: No, I don't need a similar to `glassfish-web.xml` for Wildfly. Regarding the debugging, maybe I'll give it a try later.

Comment: Wildfly 19 works? 18?

Comment: I upgraded to Wildfly 20 because it didn't work in Wildfly 19. I didn't test in 18 and don't want to use it.

Comment: Same error in 19?

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: @Marcos, have you read this https://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/ especially the "Migrating the Security Realm" part ? => The role-group mapping you have in the file `WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` should be migrated to the file `app.properties`

Comment: @Kukeltje Problem is finally solved. See answer below.

Comment: @SylvainAutran Problem is finally solved. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to give another try to the `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` annotation.

I created an *app* directory and placed the *start.xhtml* inside it.

The relevant parts of the *web.xml* file now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <display-name>autenticacao-visao</display-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>restrict</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>allowed</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/app/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>app/start.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And after that, for some reason, the application finally **worked**, I could leave the *login* page and the *start* page is shown.

Now I'm facing another little problem:

[On a successful login, SecurityContext.authenticate() returns AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE instead of AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64750354/on-a-successful-login-securitycontext-authenticate-returns-authenticationstat)