# On a successful login, SecurityContext.authenticate() returns AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE instead of AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly

- Jakarta EE 8
- Wildfly 21
- Java 11

Using *Java EE Security*, I'm trying custom form authentication in a simple application.

These are the relevant files (the description of the problem is below the files):

**CustomFormAuthenticationConfig.java**

```
package br.dev.authentication.view;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;
import javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition;
import javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.LoginToContinue;

@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
    loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(
        loginPage = "/login.xhtml",
        useForwardToLogin = false,
        errorPage = ""
    )
)
@FacesConfig
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomFormAuthenticationConfig
{
}
```

**UserAuthenticator.java**

```
package br.dev.authentication.view;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.security.enterprise.credential.Credential;
import javax.security.enterprise.credential.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.CredentialValidationResult;
import javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStore;

@ApplicationScoped
public class UserAuthenticator implements IdentityStore
{
    @Override
    public CredentialValidationResult validate(Credential credencial)
    {
        var userCredentials = (UsernamePasswordCredential) credencial;
        var userName = userCredentials.getCaller();
        var password = userCredentials.getPasswordAsString();

        if (userName.equals("1") && password.equals("1"))
        {
            return new CredentialValidationResult(userName, Set.of("USER"));
        }
        else
        {
            return CredentialValidationResult.INVALID_RESULT;
        }
    }
}
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:au="http://dev.br/authentication">

    <ui:define name="title">
        Login
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <au:errors />
        <div id="fields">
            <h:outputLabel value="User name:" for="userName" />
            <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{login.userName}" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="password" />
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{login.password}" />

            <h:commandButton value="Enter" action="#{login.authenticateUser}" />
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Login.java**

```
package br.dev.authentication.view;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.security.enterprise.AuthenticationStatus;
import javax.security.enterprise.SecurityContext;
import javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.AuthenticationParameters;
import javax.security.enterprise.credential.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class Login
{
    private String _userName;
    private String _password;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext _facesContext;
    
    @Inject
    private ExternalContext _externalContext;

    @Inject
    private SecurityContext _securityContext;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "User name is required.")
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return _userName;
    }
    
    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        _userName = userName;
    }
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required.")
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return _password;
    }
    
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        _password = password;
    }
    
    public void authenticateUser() throws IOException
    {
        // After a successful login (username and password correct),
        // executeUserAuthentication() returns AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE, 
        // and not AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS.
        // Why?
        // As a result, the code in the AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS branch above is not executed.
        AuthenticationStatus result = executeUserAuthentication();
        if (result == AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS)
        {
            _externalContext.redirect(_externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/start.xhtml");
        }
        else if (result == AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE)
        {
            _facesContext.responseComplete();
        }
        else if (result == AuthenticationStatus.SEND_FAILURE)
        {
            _facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid user name and/or password.", null));
        }
    }
    
    private AuthenticationStatus executeUserAuthentication()
    {
        return _securityContext.authenticate(
            (HttpServletRequest) _externalContext.getRequest(),
            (HttpServletResponse) _externalContext.getResponse(),
            AuthenticationParameters.withParams().credential(
                new UsernamePasswordCredential(_userName, _password))
        );
    }   
}
```

The problem is that, after a successful login (user name and password correct), as you saw in the comments in *Login* class above, the method `executeUserAuthentication()` returns `AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE` instead of `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS`. Below is an image of the application running in debug mode in the moment of execution to show this:

[image]

As a result, the browser address bar is not updated with the real url (*start.xhtml*) because the `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` branch in the code above was not executed:

[image]

I thought I was doing something wrong, but then I decided to clone this simple application from @ArjanTijms that uses the same authentication logic:

https://github.com/rieckpil/blog-tutorials/tree/master/jsf-simple-login-with-java-ee-security-api

His application is explained in this post:

https://rieckpil.de/howto-simple-form-based-authentication-for-jsf-2-3-with-java-ee-8-security-api/

And the results were the same of my application: the `AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE` branch was executed instead of the `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` branch:

[image]

No updated address bar too:

[image]

So, what's going on here? Is this a problem in the applications, Wildfly, is this correct behaviour (if so, what's the use of the `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` enum, when will it be used?)? I just want to be able to execute the redirect by myself.

**UPDATE 1**

For your information, after the `executeUserAuthentication()` the user is already authenticated: `((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getUserPrincipal()` is not null.

Some other files in the application:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <display-name>autenticacao-visao</display-name>

    <!-- ========== JSF ========== -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <!-- ========== Security ========== -->
    
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>restrict</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>allowed</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/app/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <!-- ========== Resources ========== -->
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>dev.br.RESOURCES</param-name>
        <param-value>resources</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ========== Start page ========== -->
  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>app/start.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**jboss-app.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-app>
    <security-domain>jaspitest</security-domain>
</jboss-app>
```

**start.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <ui:define name="title">
        Início
    </ui:define>
    
    <ui:define name="content">
        #{start.loggedInMessage}
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Execute" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Start.java**

```
package br.dev.authentication.view;

import java.security.Principal;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class Start
{
    @Inject
    private ExternalContext _externalContext;
    
    public String getLoggedInMessage()
    {
        Principal user = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getUserPrincipal();
        if (user != null)
        {
            return "Logged in: " + user.getName();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Not logged in";
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

After lots of tests, I noticed (at least in my application) that sometimes `SecurityContext.authenticate()` returns `AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE` and sometimes returns `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS`. Until now, I haven't figured out the reason why.

So, for the time being, I decided to solve the problem with a hack for the cases when `AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE` would be returned. So, basically, what I'm doing is redirecting to the *start* page manually. The hack is below:

**web.xml** (changed the welcome page to *redirectortostart.xhtml*)

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>app/redirectortostart.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**redirectortostart.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <ui:define name="metadados">
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{redirectorToStart.goToStart}" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**RedirectorToStart.java**

```
package br.dev.authentication.view;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class RedirectorToStart
{
    @Inject
    private ExternalContext _externalContext;

    public void goToStart() throws IOException
    {
        _externalContext.redirect(_externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/app/start.xhtml");
    }
}
```

It's not elegant, but for the time being it solves my problem. Hope someday some of you have a clue about what really could be happening with my application and could give a hint to me.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? We are seeing the same behaviour in Wildfly 26

Comment: I haven't tested if this problem was solved in newer Wildfly versions. As reported by you, it seems that it is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

The AuthenticationStatus is used as a return value by primarily the HttpAuthenticationMechanism to indicate the result (status) of the authentication process.

SEND_CONTINUE : The authentication mechanism was called and a multi-step authentication dialog with the caller has been started (for instance, the caller has been redirected to a login page). Simply said authentication is "in progress". Calling application code (if any) should not write to the response when this status is received.
[Javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/security/enterprise/AuthenticationStatus.html)

How does your web.xml looks like?

have you added the security constraints ?

Example :

```
  <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Application pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

have you the jboss-web.xml? in the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

jaspitest is the security domain to use HTTP Authentication Mechanism Interface in Wildfly/Jboss

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
  <context-root/>
  <security-domain>jaspitest</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

I just tested the application that you linked and work as Expected

[image]

you can configure the session timeout (in minutes) on the web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        1
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>false</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I updated the my question to answer your questions. Look there. Because my application is an EAR application, I use a _jboss-app.xml_ instead.

Comment: When the line `_facesContext.responseComplete();` in the method `authenticateUser()` is reached in my application, the user is already authenticated. There is no `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` after that anymore for me.

Comment: Nice, its seem that you have answered your question.

Comment: No. I answered your questions. I still don't know why `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` is not returned. After all, when will `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` ever be returned?

Comment: The web container is doing a forward to the login page under the covers, not a redirection. If `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` is not returned, there's no way for me to do the redirection to the login page that I want. If `AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE` is returned, the only thing I can do is call `_facesContext.responseComplete()`.

Comment: I usually work only with WAR files. The code seem right. Have you test put even the web container configuration (jboss-web.xml) in your src/main/wabapp/WEB-INF in the war file in your EAR file ?

Comment: As I said in my question, I also tested @ArjanTijms application (it's just a web application -> WAR file) available at https://github.com/rieckpil/blog-tutorials/tree/master/jsf-simple-login-with-java-ee-security-api . It exhibits the same problem of my application, returning `AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE` instead of `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS`.

Comment: I just tested that application and work as expected (see the added picture). Are you using the standalone-full.xml?

Comment: No. _standalone.xml_. Did you run it in Wildfly 21?

Comment: Yes, you can see that in the screenshot. Try the full configuration.

Comment: I've just tried the full configuration and got the same result, but I also noticed (before trying the ful configuration) that when I logout from the application (it has a logout button) and login again, the `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` is returned. So it seems that it just returns `AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE` when the application is first started. After logout, it returns the correct value everytime I login again. Very strange.

Comment: Ok, that's it because the Session is still alive, you can configure the session time out in the web.xml or use private surfing when testing.

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
           1
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

Comment: In the logout proccess I also invalidate the session: `request.logout(); request.getSession().invalidate()`.

Comment: Yes, it does work. And as I said, after logout, when I login again the correct `AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS` is returned.

Comment: I'll do other checks here and report any findings later. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same in my Jakarta EE 10 application on Payara 6 and still don't understand when and why I get AuthenticationStatus.SEND_CONTINUE... I only noticed one thing that after logout

```
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).logout();
return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

new login requests comes with AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS